# mod_rewrite only at this level, but not at levels below

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is there a method using mod_rewrite to have a rule which matches index.php (or whatever page in question) at "this" level of the directory structure, but not any index.php in a subdirectory below it?

For example:

http://www.domain.tld/index.php == should match, while

http://www.domain.tld/admin/index.php == should NOT match

I.e., I'm looking for a "do not descend" argument, but don't know the right phrase to search for in the documentation.  Note that we may not be talking about just a /admin, but ANY subdirectory, and that the page we're trying to match may not be at the top level like this example, but rather, at the same level as the htaccess file, wherever it is.

Comment: Make the pattern *not* match anything with a `'/'` in it.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php # match
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index$ $1/index.php # not match
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to provide exact pattern, nothing more:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ new_url.php [L]
```

The `^index\.php$` will **ONLY** match `index.php` in current folder (the same folder where .htaccess file is) and not any other location (`^` means beginning of the string while `$` means end of the string).